# How to get Wistia video facebook like count

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, video, wistia

I'm new to Wistia.com and I was wondering if there was a way to get the number of facebook likes my video has with javascript/jquery or php? I am using the Wistia API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function count_fb_like($yourUrl) {
        $json_string = file_get_contents_curl('http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?method=links.getStats&format=json&urls='.$yourUrl);
        $json = json_decode($json_string, true);
        return isset($json[0]['total_count'])?intval($json[0]['total_count']):0;
    }
    function file_get_contents_curl($url){
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);
        $cont = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_error($ch)){
            die(curl_error($ch));
        }
        return $cont;
    }
```

Comment: it gives me Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\wamp\www\mySite\video.php on line 14. Line 14 in my code is curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout); 
fix by curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60); i just updated my answer.